# A type representing any tuple?

Tags: swift, types

It seems that tuple isn't convertible to 'Any' type. Do you know a type representing any tuple?

```
func myFunc(x: Any) {
}

myFunc( [12, 34, 56] ) // OK
myFunc( (78, 90, "Hello") ) // error: '((Int, Int, String)) -> ()' is not convertible to '(Any) -> ()'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a possibility for you, I'd recommend using a generic function instead:

```
func myFunc<T>(x: T) {
}

myFunc( [12, 34, 56] ) // OK
myFunc( (78, 90, "Hello") ) // Fine too
```

But it's hard to tell without knowing what exactly you're doing in your function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to cast it explicitly, but then it works:

```
func myFunc(x: Any) {
}

myFunc( (78, 90, "Hello") as Any)
```

I suppose that is necessary as the more common case of passing a tuple to a function is to have the tuple decompose into the separate parameters of the function (as opposed to being a parameter itself).

Answer (score 0):

I saw [SwiftyBeaver's code](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver/blob/master/sources/SwiftyBeaver.swift#L91) (thanks). Then I wrote this with their way.

```
func myFunc(@autoclosure a: () -> Any) {
    let x = a()
}

myFunc( [12, 34, 56] ) // OK
myFunc( (78, 90, "Hello") ) // OK, too
```